# Conditional sum of two 3D arrays; condition is a 1D array

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

I want to add two 3D (shape (N, 3)) numpy arrays conditionally where the condition is specified as a 1D array (shape of N).

What's an efficient (vectorized) way to do this? numpy.where() only supports a conditional operation where all three arrays (including the condition) have matching dimensions.

For instance:

```
a = np.asarray([[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4]])
b = np.asarray([[0.2, 0.2], [0.3, 0.3], [0.4, 0.4], [0.5, 0.5]])
c = np.asarray([0, 1, 1, 0])
```

I would like to be able to do:

```
np.where(c == 1, a + b, a)
```

i.e., do an element-wise add of a + b as long as the corresponding element in c is equal to 1 at the same index in the array.

However, I get an error instead:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,) (4,3) (4,3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use boolean indexing:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randint(20, 30, size=(5, 3))
#[[23 29 23]
# [20 27 24]
# [28 26 26]
# [27 20 26]
# [23 24 23]]
b = np.random.randint(20, 30, size=(5, 3))
#[[22 25 20]
# [28 29 20]
# [29 22 29]
# [28 28 21]
# [22 26 27]]
c = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=5).astype(bool)
# [ True  True  True False False]
r = a + b
r[~c] = a[~c] # keeping the default value if the corresponding value is 0 (or False) in c.
print(r)
```

```
[[45 54 43]
 [48 56 44]
 [57 48 55]
 [27 20 26]
 [23 24 23]]
```

Comment: This works but without negating c since I actually want the operation (sum) to occur if the mask value (c) is true. Thanks!

Comment: @user2180977 The operation already happened at `r = a + b`. I only restored the values of `a` where the mask is `False`. This is eqvivalent with `np.where(c == 1, a + b, a)`, isn't it?